# Magento2: How to restrict customer dashboard links in frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, customer-group, dashboard

How can i restrict customer dashboard links for specific customer group  in magento2 frontend

[image]

Comment: Customer desh board link means customer account all pages?

Comment: Yes, i want to hide links in customer account all pages

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use event

> controller_action_predispatch_customer

**On this event fire an observer:* which will redirect a customer to  **home whenever they are loggin and try access customer page**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class StopAccountAccess implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_helper;
    protected $_actionFlag;


    protected $messageManager;

    protected $redirect;
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        Session $customerSession


    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->session = $customerSession;

    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {


            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $actionname = $controller->getRequest()->getActionName();
            $controllername= $controller->getRequest()->getControllerName();

            $disableredirectionAction  = array('loginPost','loginPost')
             array(
            'create',
            'login',
            'forgotpassword',
            'forgotpasswordpost',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'confirm',
            'confirmation',
            'loginPost',
            'loginpost',
            'logoutsuccess',
            'logout'

        );
              $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $disableredirectionAction) . ')/i';

            if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() && !preg_match($pattern, $action) ) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('You cannot access account pages'));
                $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), '');
             }   



        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added screenshot above, please check

Comment: You need add another event controller_action_predispatch_{fullActionname}

Comment: i want to hide the frontend customer dashboard links for particular users

Comment: Yes, possible..,If you  customer object then you can do